# ¿Cómo subir sistema web a un servidor local?

Tags: php, servidor, windows-server

Tengo una duda enorme y necesito un poco de asesoría.

Resulta que tengo un sistema web terminado desarrollado en PHP y MySQL (utilicé XAMPP), y deseo subir este proyecto a un servidor local, y que todas las PCs en la red puedan tener acceso al sistema.

El S.O. del servidor es Windows Server 2012, y no tiene nada instalado.

¿Cómo podría subir mi sistema web al servidor local, para que todos lo equipos conectados a la red, puedan tener acceso? ¿ Qué pasos debería seguir?

He estado investigando, y algunos recomiendan instalar el XAMPP en el servidor, y tocar temas de VHosts y Firewall, pero aún me queda la duda...

Gracias a todos de antemano.

Comment: Tal vez leyendo la documentación puedas lograr tu objetivo... Primero, dónde ubicar tus archivos PHP/HTML, luego la instalación del motor de la base de datos y la creación de la base de datos en si misma, la corrección de las rutas de los archivos, el puerto, si hay un servidor DNS en la red...

Comment: @Nick Yo la tengo de la siguiente manera, mi PC es el servidor y la red cableada no existe, solo usamos todos un mismo router wifi. Para ellos conectarse al sistema en vez de ser **[http://localhost/sistema/](http://localhost/sistema/)**  reemplaza el localhost por la dirección ip del servidor **[http://192.168.1.101/sistema/](http://192.168.1.101/sistema/)** y listo